# How do I define the struct function,getting error message

Tags: c

I'm new to programming and now im trying to learn struct. I'm getting some error message which says. Incomplete type is not allowed, incomlete class type `struct ShoppingList` is not allowed, `shoppingList` uses undefined struct `shoppingList` and left of `.length` must have struct union type.

All those problem seems are comming from the line.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

struct shoppingList
{
    char addItem[100];
    char printList[100];
    char removeItem;
    char  editItem;
    char saveList;
    char loadList;

};





int main(void)
{
    struct ShoppingList shoppingList;
    shoppingList.length = 0; 
    int option = 0;

    do
    {
        printf("\n\nWelcome to the shopping list manager!\n");
        printf("=====================================\n\n");

        printf("1. Add an item\n");
        printf("2. Display the shopping list\n");
        printf("3. Remove an item\n");
        printf("4. Change an item\n");
        printf("5. Save list\n"); 
        printf("6. Load list\n"); 
        printf("7. Exit\n");

        printf("What do you want to do? ");
        scanf("%d", &option);

        switch (option)
        {
        case 1: addItem(&shoppingList); break;
        case 2: printList(&shoppingList); break;
        case 3: removeItem(&shoppingList); break;
        case 4: editItem(&shoppingList); break;
        case 5: saveList(&shoppingList); break; 
        case 6: loadList(&shoppingList); break; 
        case 7: break;
        default:
            printf("Please enter a number between 1 and 7");
        }
    } while (option != 7);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have a typo shoppingList vs ShoppingList  should be `struct ShoppingList`

Comment: ok,i fix it but im still getting the "shoppingList" has no field "length" and 'length': is not a member of 'ShoppingList'

Comment: That's because your struct does not have a `length` member.